# Cannot decode CRS from executable JAR with GeoTools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, epsg

I decode a CRS from its EPSG code using:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3035");
```

This works like a charm, but when the same line of code is executed from an executable *.jar program, the following error occurs:

> Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:3035" for authority "EPSG" was found for an object of type "EngineeringCRS".

It seems the EPSG codes can no longer be decoded. This is confirmed by:

```
System.out.println(CRS.getSupportedAuthorities(true));
System.out.println(CRS.getSupportedCodes("EPSG").size());
```

which returns

> [EPSG, http://www.opengis.net/gml, http://www.opengis.net/def, AUTO2, AUTO, urn:ogc:def, urn:x-ogc:def, CRS]
>
> 6741

from the original code, but:

> [EPSG, http://www.opengis.net/gml, AUTO2, AUTO, urn:ogc:def, urn:x-ogc:def, CRS, http://www.opengis.net/def]
>
> 2

once executed from the *.jar program.

I am stuck for hours with this issue...

Changing the dependency from `gt-epsg-hsql` to `gt-epsg-wkt` did not fix the problem. When unzipping the *.jar file, the EPSG database is there, but it seems it cannot be read.

The *.jar program is produced using the *maven-assembly-plugin*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed [this section](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) of the FAQ, which describes a proper way to produce an executable *.jar from GeoTools.

Using *[maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)* instead of *maven-assembly-plugin* fixed the issue.
I had in addition to deal with invalid signatures as described [here](http://zhentao-li.blogspot.com/2012/06/maven-shade-plugin-invalid-signature.html).

This is how the pom.xml looks like in the end:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>org.package.MyMainClass</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```